# TS2322: Type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; body: Stock[]; } | null' is not assignable to type 'Stock[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics, typescript2.0

I am getting this TypeScript error in Angular. I have a class named StockComponent with the following property:

`protected stocks: Stock[] = [];`

The Stock class is a regular class I created to represent a Stock entity. I am trying to get this to work:

```
this.http.get<{headers: HttpHeaders, body: Stock[]}>('https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/stock/', {
  observe: 'response'
}).subscribe((response) => {
  this.total = Number(response.headers.get('X-WP-Total'));

  this.total_pages = Number(response.headers.get('X-WP-TotalPages'));

  this.stocks = response.body;
});
```

I see this error when I try assigning the body to `this.stocks`. The problem resolves if I change `Stock[] = []` to `Stock[]|any = []`

How can I make this work right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Body is an optional attribute, to declare to TS that it's an array you can use instanceof operator.

```
if (response.body instanceof Array) {
   this.stocks = response.body
} else {
   this.stocks =[]
}
```

Comment: Doing that results in the following error:

```
Error: src/app/stocks/stocks.component.ts:34:7 - error TS2322: Type 'never[] | { headers: HttpHeaders; body: Stock[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Stock[]'.
  Type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; body: Stock[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Stock[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.

34       this.stocks = response.body ? response.body : [];
```

Comment: Let try this.stocks = response.body.body?response.body.body:[];

Comment: That fixes the error however the value of `this.stocks` is now `[]` because there is no `body.body` in the response. There's just one body property.

Comment: Ok, so try use instanceof to declare TS that data is Array

        if (response.body instanceof Array) {
          this.stocks = response.body
        }

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Is this the right way though or a hack?

Comment: This is a right way. Maybe there is an more elegant way